# NP or Not? Finding a word in an existing dictionary surrounded by Gibberish

Tags: string, dictionary, np

So a friend and I have a question which we can't find an answer to.

Given a String of unknown length or size covered in gibberish note the word CAN be misspelled by one or two charachters. Is it possible to figure out what that word is supposed to be.

An Example: we have a dictionary ['apple','banana','potato]

is it possible to find wether or not any of these words are in a string that looks something like this:

alxcsfapple saodpjkasf (or it could be misspspelled like this amncbxanana

he thinks the only way to do is n! However could we optimize this by using a form of autocorrect that assumes the start of a new word after each letter in conjunction with a trie in a non n! way?
Is this problem NP?

Answer (score 1):

This search can be done in `O(len(hay) * len(needle))` time using a modified [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) metric: namely, the zeroth row for the hay is to be initialized to zeros (which means we can start from any position of the hay for free). So this is not NP.

For details, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching#Problem_formulation_and_algorithms and http://ginstrom.com/scribbles/2007/12/01/fuzzy-substring-matching-with-levenshtein-distance-in-python/.